# Why does the RMI registry need my remote interface class file?

Tags: java, rmi

This question was asked before (roughly speaking). It got one answer which required clarification. The answer to the request for clarification was non-responsive.

I write a Remote interface RX and develop the implementation "class RXImpl implements RX." In my RMI server I instantiate and export RXImpl, obtaining a stub along the way:

```
RXImpl obj  = new RXImpl();
RX     stub = (RX)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject( obj, 0 );
```

My understanding (which of course may be wrong) is that all the hard work is done. I just need some way to tell potential clients where to find the stub, and I do that with the registry:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
registry.rebind( "rmi:some_arbitrary_name", stub );
```

But if the registry can't find RX.class in its codebase I get a RemoteException with the nested exception "ClassNotFoundException: RX."

If all the registry needs to do is tell clients where an existing stub lives why does it need a codebase that contains RX.class?

Thanks.

Comment: The stub implements RX.  Thus, in order to interact with the stub class, the RX class must be available on the classpath.  This applies to all RMI clients (and the registry is effectively a client).

Answer (score 1):

> If all the registry needs to do is tell clients where an existing stub lives

That's not an accurate description. The Registry is basically a remote hash table which maps bind names to stubs. It doesn't 'tell clients were an existing stub lives', it *returns stubs*, via RMI, as objects. The stubs don't 'live' elsewhere, they are *in* the Registry's hashmap, having been put there by the bind step, also via RMI.

> why does it need a codebase that contains RX.class?

Because, [as you have already been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671325/why-does-simple-rmi-server-need-codebase), the Registry is an RMI server so it obeys the same rules as all other RMI components.

Comment: This helps. But in what way does the registry interact with the stub that requires it to have the interface class? I can accept that the registry obeys the same rules as other RMI components, but there is a reason for those rules; what is the reason for this one?

Comment: If I make RXImpl implement `interface EZInterface{}` the registry doesn't seem to care. But if I make it `interface EZInterface extends Remote` I now get a "class not found exception EZInterface." So it's not just a serialization issue; apparently the registry is looking for the class files for all Remote interfaces. Why? My client is going to ask for "the stub bound to the name rats"; not "the stub bound to the name rats that implements the RX interface."

Comment: @JackStraub It 'interacts with the stub' by receiving it via RMI.  As I've already stated, once here and once elsewhere, RMI requires access to the stub class and everything it depends on at both ends. If your interface doesn't extend `Remote` the object that implements it will be serialized entirely to the Registry instead of being passed as a stub, and if it isn't serializable you will get a `NotSerializableException` instead.